# Are there any frameworks specifically for backbone.js that are made for animated web pages

Tags: animation, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-boilerplate

So I started with a purchased web template that has a bunch of backbone.js code in it.  Each view animates in and out.  I started to play extensively with it and basically rewrote alot of stuff and completely ripped out the animation engine he was using and replaced it with tweenmax JS.  Now I am contemplating a new website and want to use another backbone.js framework but I don't know if using the same project I used before and sticking with that system is the right answer or if anyone with backbone.js knowledge can tell me which framework would be best suited for creating "Designer" style webpages where you have the usual content. Home, About Us, Portfolio, Contact Us, Blog, etc.   I specifically want to be able to load pages in and out and have full control over the views that animate in and out, but I don't know which framework helper is best suited for someone with my intentions.   I looked at Marionette, Boilerplate, a combination of the two and also at [BackboneMVC](http://chance-an.github.com/backbone-mvc/#root/index).  Before I get knee deep into learning a new framework helper I would like to find out as much as possible so I don't have to change directions too many times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Marionette used in a number of highly styled, animation heavy apps in the last year. Not the least of which is the Halo Waypoint website for Halo 4: https://app.halowaypoint.com/

Most of the Backbone frameworks out there would be good choices, I would think. Very few of them really restrict you in how you move between views. Though Marionette may provide some challenges in this, with it's heavy use of Region objects to control the display of specific view instances.

You would need to write custom region objects to set up the animations. This can be done using the sample "fading region" that I built, here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/320#issuecomment-9746319

Hope that helps.